# Magento Cron not working

Tags: cron, crontab

For some reason my Cron is not working anymore in my Magento 1.9.3 store.

I tried it by running it manually, but both solutions did not give any error, still zero results in the AOE Scheduler task list. Non of them are running.

I tried:

```
https://www.domain.com/cron.php
```

and by SH

```
sh /path/to/my/magento/root/cron.sh
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do your `cron.php` / `cron.sh` have executable permission (chmod +x)? Make a backup of your `cron_schedule` database table and drop all content of it then re-run cron.

Comment: @JonathanRibas Thanks! Checked it and permissions are fine, after dropping the content in de db and tried it again, it stil does not work. Cronlist is not filled again and non of the crons are running.

Comment: When running cron execution command, do you see any errors in your Magento logs (var/log/) or php log?

Comment: @JonathanRibas Sadly, I do not receive any errors. So its quite hard to debug the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in your local environment? If so enable xdebug and put some breakpoints in your code to see where the problem is.

Comment: @JonathanRibas Thats the strange part, I can not reproduce it. It suddenly stopped last night at 22.11h. That was the list time the cron run well. After that it did not work anymore.

Comment: Check if there are processes running cron.php or cron.sh on your server, if so kill them and re-run cron again.

Comment: @JonathanRibas What is the best way to check if there a processes running?

Comment: `ps aux | grep 'cron'`

Comment: @JonathanRibas Adding `$isShellDisabled = true;` to the cron.php file, solve the problem, then the cron by php is working well. But I really do not like that solution. So am I missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't edit core files, check AOE documentation again step by step to configure your cron.

Comment: @JonathanRibas Check the cron that where running, but there are non cronjobs running.

Comment: Have you fix your problem?